# Process daily tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am making a laravel based system that going to save millions of records in a single table daily. to overcome this issue i came up with an idea to save data to daily identical tables. (note table structure is the same)

Ex: table_20200501, table_20200502, table_20200503

now the issue is when i am querying the data. if someone search data between 2020-05-01 and 2020-05-02 how do i connect those two tables and return data without writing raw queries (not using a model). also i am using datatable server site processing as well.

it would be a big help if someone can help this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like you need a Union query, Laravel does provide functionality for Unions: [Docs for Union Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#unions)

Comment: You might want to consider Elasticsearch as an alternative.

Comment: Is there any way we can use a model without calling DB::table() ? but thanks this one worked.

Comment: not that I know of, you'd need a different model class for each table, and then the collection of results would be made up of different models, I'm not sure if eloquent can do that.